# Tkinter: Draw rectangle using a mouse

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, mouseevent

Please, help me to resolve this problem.

I want to allow the user to draw a random rectangle around a specific region of interest in a picture using the mouse ( by clicking the right or left button of the mouse until he releases it).

I deal with large images (images larger than the resolution of my screen, such as this [one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose#/media/File:Rose_Amber_Flush_20070601.jpg)), so the user needs to scroll the window in order to be able to see the picture fully.

Here is the code I tried just to display a large picture, but I have no idea on how to allow the user to draw using his mouse a rectangle over an object (say a person in a picture):

```
from Tkinter import *
import Image,ImageTk

root=Tk()
canv=Canvas(root,relief=SUNKEN)

sbarv=Scrollbar(root,orient=VERTICAL)
sbarh=Scrollbar(root,orien=HORIZONTAL)

sbarv.config(command=canv.yview)
sbarh.config(command=canv.xview)

canv.config(yscrollcommand=sbarv.set)
canv.config(xscrollcommand=sbarh.set)

canv.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=N+S+E+W)
sbarv.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=N+S)

sbarh.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=E+W)


im=Image.open("image.jpg")
width,height=im.size
canv.config(scrollregion=(0,0,width,height))
im2=ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
imgtag=canv.create_image(0,0,anchor="nw",image=im2)

root.mainloop()
```

**EDIT 1:**

- The rectangle must not be filled. I mean I want to draw only its 4 lines (segments) but it must be empty inside, I want to draw only its contours in one pixel width.
- I also want to draw as the cursor is moving (dragging) not after button release.
- Also, note that the rectangle to draw may be a long one, I mean the vertical scroll-bar will need to move down to be able to delimitate the whole object of interest (let's say it is a person)

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you very much in advance

**EDIT 2:**

Following the link given to me above, I coded this. My problem is that the **scroll-bars do not appear**. May be someone could tell me why ?

Note that in this code, I resolved the first and second problems highlighted in **EDIT 1**:

```
import PIL.Image
import Image
import ImageTk
from Tkinter import *    


class ExampleApp(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        Frame.__init__(self,master=None)
        self.x = self.y = 0
        self.canvas = Canvas(master,  cursor="cross")

        self.sbarv=Scrollbar(self,orient=VERTICAL)
        self.sbarh=Scrollbar(self,orient=HORIZONTAL)
        self.sbarv.config(command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.sbarh.config(command=self.canvas.xview)

        self.canvas.config(yscrollcommand=self.sbarv.set)
        self.canvas.config(xscrollcommand=self.sbarh.set)

        self.canvas.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=N+S+E+W)
        self.sbarv.grid(row=0,column=1,stick=N+S)
        self.sbarh.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=E+W)

        self.canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.on_button_press)
        self.canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.on_move_press)
        self.canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.on_button_release)

        self.rect = None

        self.start_x = None
        self.start_y = None


        self.im = PIL.Image.open("logo.png")
        self.wazil,self.lard=self.im.size
        self.canvas.config(scrollregion=(0,0,self.wazil,self.lard))
        self.tk_im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.im)
        self.canvas.create_image(0,0,anchor="nw",image=self.tk_im)   


    def on_button_press(self, event):
        # save mouse drag start position
        self.start_x = event.x
        self.start_y = event.y

        # create rectangle if not yet exist
        #if not self.rect:
        self.rect = self.canvas.create_rectangle(self.x, self.y, 1, 1, fill="")

    def on_move_press(self, event):
        curX, curY = (event.x, event.y)

        # expand rectangle as you drag the mouse
        self.canvas.coords(self.rect, self.start_x, self.start_y, curX, curY)    


    def on_button_release(self, event):
        pass    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root=Tk()
    app = ExampleApp(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This should help: [Drawing rectangle using mouse events in Tkinter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24135170/drawing-rectangle-using-mouse-events-in-tkinter)

Comment: @CraigBurgler thank you very much, i will see what i can do with the answer in that link.

Comment: @CraigBurgler you can check my second edit, if you want

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The Scrollbars do not show because you `grid` them into a Frame (`self.sbarv=Scrollbar(self, ...)`) which you do not place into the parent window. You directly grid the Canvas into the parent window though (`self.canvas = Canvas(master, ...)`).

What you should do is also put the Canvas in `self` and then pack the Frame into the master window using

```
app = ExampleApp(root)
app.pack()
```

However, when scrolling, the `event.x` and `event.y` do not represent the correct position on tha canvas anymore, so you should use

```
self.start_x = self.canvas.canvasx(event.x)
self.start_y = self.canvas.canvasy(event.y)
```

and

```
curX = self.canvas.canvasx(event.x)
curY = self.canvas.canvasy(event.y)
```

Then, I understand you want to automatically scroll the canvas when the mouse is dragging to one of the borders of the canvas? To do that, you need to check if the mouse is at one of the edges of the canvas and scroll in that direction if it is. You can use something like:

```
w, h = self.canvas.winfo_width(), self.canvas.winfo_height()
if event.x > 0.9*w:
    self.canvas.xview_scroll(1, 'units') 
elif event.x < 0.1*w:
    self.canvas.xview_scroll(-1, 'units')
if event.y > 0.9*h:
    self.canvas.yview_scroll(1, 'units') 
elif event.y < 0.1*h:
    self.canvas.yview_scroll(-1, 'units')
```

So, all that implemented in your code becomes:

```
import PIL.Image
import Image
import ImageTk
from Tkinter import *    


class ExampleApp(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        Frame.__init__(self,master=None)
        self.x = self.y = 0
        self.canvas = Canvas(self,  cursor="cross")

        self.sbarv=Scrollbar(self,orient=VERTICAL)
        self.sbarh=Scrollbar(self,orient=HORIZONTAL)
        self.sbarv.config(command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.sbarh.config(command=self.canvas.xview)

        self.canvas.config(yscrollcommand=self.sbarv.set)
        self.canvas.config(xscrollcommand=self.sbarh.set)

        self.canvas.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=N+S+E+W)
        self.sbarv.grid(row=0,column=1,stick=N+S)
        self.sbarh.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=E+W)

        self.canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.on_button_press)
        self.canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.on_move_press)
        self.canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.on_button_release)

        self.rect = None

        self.start_x = None
        self.start_y = None

        self.im = PIL.Image.open("logo.png")
        self.wazil,self.lard=self.im.size
        self.canvas.config(scrollregion=(0,0,self.wazil,self.lard))
        self.tk_im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.im)
        self.canvas.create_image(0,0,anchor="nw",image=self.tk_im)   


    def on_button_press(self, event):
        # save mouse drag start position
        self.start_x = self.canvas.canvasx(event.x)
        self.start_y = self.canvas.canvasy(event.y)

        # create rectangle if not yet exist
        if not self.rect:
            self.rect = self.canvas.create_rectangle(self.x, self.y, 1, 1, outline='red')

    def on_move_press(self, event):
        curX = self.canvas.canvasx(event.x)
        curY = self.canvas.canvasy(event.y)

        w, h = self.canvas.winfo_width(), self.canvas.winfo_height()
        if event.x > 0.9*w:
            self.canvas.xview_scroll(1, 'units') 
        elif event.x < 0.1*w:
            self.canvas.xview_scroll(-1, 'units')
        if event.y > 0.9*h:
            self.canvas.yview_scroll(1, 'units') 
        elif event.y < 0.1*h:
            self.canvas.yview_scroll(-1, 'units')

        # expand rectangle as you drag the mouse
        self.canvas.coords(self.rect, self.start_x, self.start_y, curX, curY)    

    def on_button_release(self, event):
        pass    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root=Tk()
    app = ExampleApp(root)
    app.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I do not know how to thank you, Sir. I was struggling with this problem during 4 days before asking here. Thank you so much for the detailed and convincing explanation.

Comment: you even resolved a problem I encountered but did not mention: drawing a new rectangle must erase the former one. Thank you a lot again.

Comment: You pretty much already had that fixed yourself, but it was commented out. The line `if not self.rect:` makes sure that only once a rectangle is created and after that this one rectangle's position is changed.

Comment: that is sad I can not upvote 1000 times on your answer