# Tkinter: getting coordinates of a mouse drawn rectangle

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Working on the answer of my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29789554/tkinter-draw-rectangle-using-a-mouse), I wonder how to get the coordinates of the 4 pixels representing the corners of the rectangle as well as its 2 dimensions ?

Comment: It seems those values are in `self.start_x`, `self.start_y`, `curX` and `curY`. What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`canvas.bbox(item)`](https://web.archive.org/web/20201108093851/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.bbox-method) to get the coordinates of the bounding box of an item on the canvas. Because your item is a rectangle, the bounding box exactly represents the rectangle.
In your case it would be:

```
self.canvas.bbox(self.rect)
```

This returns a tuple containing `(x0, y0, x1, y1)` in which point 0 is the upper left corner and point 1 is the lower right corner.
You can easily convert these to the four corners and sizes:

```
Upper left  = x0, y0
Upper right = x1, y0
Lower left  = x0, y1
Lower right = x1, y1

width  = x1-x0
height = y1-y0
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the x,y coordinates contained in the `event` parameter of the `on_button_press()` and `on_button_release()` methods:

```
width = abs(xRelease - xPress)
height = abs(yRelease - yPress)
```